# Formula evaluation in excel using Apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am trying to read from the Excel 2007 worksheet. The problem in reading the excel sheet is that all its cell has values in the type of formula.

The values of the cell are like:

**='C:\**\**\[***.xlsx]***'!G23**

When I try to read them using formula evaluation it gives me the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not resolve external workbook name '/**/**.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up.
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:109)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:84)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.getRef3DEval(OperationEvaluationContext.java:309)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getEvalForPtg(WorkbookEvaluator.java:634)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateFormula(WorkbookEvaluator.java:505)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluateAny(WorkbookEvaluator.java:263)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.evaluate(WorkbookEvaluator.java:205)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCellValue(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:267)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateFormulaCell(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:154)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:346)
at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(HSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:337)
at org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFFormulaEvaluator.evaluateAllFormulaCells(XSSFFormulaEvaluator.java:241)
at com.kiodex.ExcelWorkbook2007.parse(ExcelWorkbook2007.java:26)
at ExcelTest.main(ExcelTest.java:24)
    Caused by: org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment$WorkbookNotFoundException: Could not resolve external workbook name '/**/**.xlsx'. Workbook environment has not been set up.
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment.getWorkbookEvaluator(CollaboratingWorkbooksEnvironment.java:194)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.WorkbookEvaluator.getOtherWorkbookEvaluator(WorkbookEvaluator.java:156)
at org.apache.poi.ss.formula.OperationEvaluationContext.createExternSheetRefEvaluator(OperationEvaluationContext.java:107)
... 13 more
```

The sheet has proper values but as they are of formula type, when we try to evaluate it, it gives the error for the excel which is referenced in the formula.

I tried doing all possible ways given in the below link.
[Formula Evaluation Apache](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) but it does not work.

Please help.

Comment: Looks similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26881400/how-to-update-excel-sheet-links-using-poi

Comment: Yeah.. But it does not have a proper solution.. :(

Comment: Did you try setting up the external workbook references [as detailed in the Apache POI documentation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html#external)? How far did that get you?

Comment: Actually the problem was, we didn't had the excel sheet which it was referring to. :(

Comment: In your excel workbook, some cells might have referenced with another Excel sheet (workbook name '/**/**.xlsx'),  remove that reference then apply the formula evaluator. Then it will work.

Answer (score 2):

I have had same error today. Because due to some data loss issues I created new excel file from old one and changed its name. When I evaluate formulas in new excel file,it has given this error with its old name.Following line solved problem like a charm:

```
wb.setForceFormulaRecalculation(true)
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

```
var bcd = sheet1.Workbook.GetCreationHelper().CreateFormulaEvaluator();
bcd.IgnoreMissingWorkbooks = true;
bcd.EvaluateAll();
```

Comment: While only adding code might solve the issue, an explanation would help the OP and future readers to understand better what the issue was and how it can be solved.